# Should I use Autoreleasepool in library

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, nsautoreleasepool

I have a header file (C Like)

And I have to make an Obj-c library (or just couple of .m -s) that implements it.

Whoever will call the library will be a C program.

However I don't want to manually deal with memory allocations and I want to use ARC.

May I use `autoreleasepool{}` inside my functions in order to have ARC working and functioning...

Or I have to go back in couple years/uninstall my laziness and do this manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May I use autoreleasepool{} inside my functions in order to have ARC working and functioning...

`@autoreleasepool` is not only for ARC. You can use `@autoreleasepool` with both `-fobjc-arc` and `-fno-objc-arc`.

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#autoreleasepool

> @autoreleasepool may be used in non-ARC translation units, with equivalent semantics.

Besides,

> Whoever will call the library will be a C program.

**EDITED**

You mean the application program is written in C language and the library program is written in Objective-C language? In that case, you should use `@autoreleasepool` in your code. Usually, for OS X Cocoa application, there is a runloop that has Autorelease Pool, so no need to have `@autoreleasepool` in your code till some certain situation (for example, avoiding huge amount of memory usage).

**EDITED**

Anyway, you can use ARC in your library code, but it should be compiled with `-fobjc-arc` option.

Comment: Thanks ! I was doubt it won't solve my problem. Btw it is not application it is daemon... So there will not be any autorekease pull outside of the obj-c library.

Answer (score 2):

> May I use autoreleasepool{} inside my functions in order to have ARC working and functioning...

Yes. And if you're being called from C, you *must* do so at every C entry point or you will almost certainly leak memory. If you fail to do so, you should see messages on the console like "Autoreleased object while no autorelease pool. Just leaking."

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I gave my vote for more detailed answer. but thanks a lot !

Comment: Actually since iOS 7 / Mac OS X 10.9 if you autorelease with no pool it will not leak or print a message.

Comment: This is a very important answer.  Thank you.